# How to pass a c-array to a method in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, opengl

I'm currently trying to pass an array of GLfloat to a method as follows :

```
[_squareModel setVertexData:gCubeVertexData : 216];
```

and

```
- (void)setVertexData:(GLfloat*)vertexData : (int)size
{
GLfloat vData[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    vData[i] = vertexData[i];

}
_vertexData = vData;

glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_vertexData), _vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

}
```

gCubeVertexData is an array of GLfloat with size 216. When I pass it into the method, however, it becomes transforms into a GLfloat pointer and loses all data with the exception of the first number. I have been trying to find an explanation for this, but none of the answers I have uncovered have worked. Is there any way to fix this, or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: What is `_vertexData` and why are you taking the `sizeof` it?  It looks like a pointer from the way you assigned to it.

Comment: I agree with JS1, the `vertexData` that you pass to the method is fine, but `_vertexData` has many possible problems. How is `_vertexData` defined?

Comment: _vertexData was defined in the header as a GLfloat*, but as in Ken's answer below, I never needed it in the first place, so I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass C arrays in just the same way as in C and as you have in your code snippet.

Actually, C doesn't allow for arrays to be passed. It only allows pointers to be passed. But arrays degenerate to pointers very easily and silently.

This is an important distinction. One of the classic traps in not understanding the distinction is using `sizeof` on a pointer and expecting to get the size of the array it points to. That doesn't work. `sizeof` on a pointer gives you the size of the pointer itself (usually 8 or 4 bytes, depending on the architecture (64 vs. 32 bits)).

Once an array has degenerated into a pointer, there's no way to get the size of the original array from that pointer.

That's probably the problem in your code, although you don't show what `_vertextData` is. It pretty much has to be a pointer, given how you're using it.

Anyway, you're passing in the number of elements of `vertexData` so you can compute its size. You shouldn't need either `vdata` or `_vertexData`, at least for this. Just pass `size * sizeof(*vertexData)`:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size * sizeof(*vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Note, that's `sizeof(*vertexData)` with an asterisk, which means the size of the type to which `vertexData` points (`GLfloat`). That's not the same as `sizeof(vertexData)` with no asterisk, which means the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help; my code still isn't currently working, but I am fairly sure the problem's root lies somewhere else.